# Load Galleria when navigating to specific Jquerytools tab

Tags: javascript, galleria, jquery, jquery-tools

I'm having trouble to integrate the Galleria image gallery plugin onto one of my Jquerytools tabs. When navigating directly to the page with Galleria (example: www.domain.com/index.php#tabnameofgalleriapane), there's no problem.

Whenever the pane with galleria is not loaded immediately (default pane is another pane), Gallery throws an error: `Fatal error: Could not extract a stage height from the CSS. Traced height: 0px.`, which is logical, because when the Galleria pane is not active, it's css is probably `display:none;`...

Defining the height & width literally does not seem to work. This was the previous setup:

```
jQuery("#jp_nav").tabs(".jp_pane", { history: true } );
jQuery('#gallery').galleria({
    imageCrop: false,
    transition: 'slide',
    autoplay: 7000,
    width: 960,
    height: 640
});
```

So I was thinking to bind the load of the Galleria plugin onload of the pane that contains the Galleria plugin, because in that moment, the Galleria pane does have a height... I've found something to help me on my way, but now I'm getting other JavaScript conflict errors (see below for explanation).

```
jQuery("#jp_nav").tabs(".jp_pane", {
  initialIndex: 0,
  onBeforeClick: function(event, i) {
    // get the pane to be opened
    var pane = this.getPanes().eq(i);
    var src = this.getTabs().eq(i).attr("href");
    pane.load(src, "#jp_images", function(){
        jQuery('#gallery').galleria({
            imageCrop: false,
            transition: 'slide',
            autoplay: 7000,
            width: 960,
            height: 640
        });  
    });
  },
  history: true
});
```

For reasons beyond my control, the website I'm writing this for uses both jQuery and Prototype/Scriptaculous. So please take into account that the script has to be written in noConflict mode. (Which I'm doing in my setup `$.noConflict();`)

Can someone please tell me if the script below puts me on the right track? 
Can someone help me modify the script to work when the #jp_images tab is loaded?
Right now, the above script gives me conflict errors with Prototype.

Anxiously awaiting your expert views!

Regards,

Maarten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to find a quick and dirty solution (thanks to [vfxdude](http://www.vfxdude.com/forum/topic/gallery-not-working-inside-tabs))

Anytime the tab with the Galleria is clicked, I force a page reload, like so:

```
tabName = 'jp_images';
jQuery('#jp_nav a[href="#'+tabName+'"]').click(function() { if (location.hash == '') location.replace(location.href+'/#'+tabName); });
```

After this, I can just use the regular old Galleria plugin initialisation.

Granted, it is a little dirty, but it's an easy and quick fix for when on a deadline.